# Tagging imported BibTex entries in TiddlyWiki 5

Tags: tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I'd like to use TW5 to support a literature review, and the BibTeX import looks very useful. I am dragging a .bib file onto TW, and an import list is produced, one entry per article. Works well, and the tiddlys produced have the info in usefully named fields.

I would like to tag each entry of that list so I can find them later. Either at the "import list" stage, or once they have been imported (without finding each one individually).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of tagging them you could use a field that always appears in the bibtex tiddlers (and never in any other tiddler)  as an indicator, for example `bibtex-title`. This way you can retrieve all the bibtex tiddlers like this:

```
{{{[has[bibtex-title]]}}}
```

In case you're interested [my webpage](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/%7Emoreaue) has an example of this technique (it's a bit messy, see some explanations [here](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/%7Emoreaue/#MakingOf))